# How to explain difference of importance between feature selection and model quality?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, feature-selection, text-mining

I have a data collection with a mixed feature set consisting of both numerical features and text features. The number of numerical features is quite small, i.e., 6, comparing to the number of text features, i.e., 2000. ( The data set is a csv file, where there are 6 columns consisting of digit values only; other columns are just plain texts). We found that removing these numerical features (columns) in fact improves the performance. However, when we conduct the feature selection based on the information gain, looks like those numerical features gets more weight. How to explain this scenario?

Comment: What technique(s) are you using for feature selection and classification?

Comment: I used SVM to do the classification. I use information gain to do the feature selection.

Comment: Are you scaling the feature vector data for the SVM?